# jQuery each loop get selected info from all levels except last level

Tags: jquery

I am having an issue with jQuery trying to select every anchor item *except* ones within the last ul.

Example HTML (simplified versioon)

```
<div id="foo">
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="active"><span>xxxxx</span></a>
            <ul class="level2">
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><span>xxxxx</span></a>
                    <ul class="level3">
                        <li><a href="#"><span>xxxxx</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><span>xxxxx</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><span>xxxxx</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><span>xxxxx</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>   
    </ul>
</nav>
</div>
```

Some example jQuery I have tried (but fails and returns all anchors)

```
var menu = $('#foo');
        menu.find( "nav ul:not(:last) a" ).each(function() {
            console.log($(this).text() );
        });
```

The above returns all 6 anchors from the example.

I only want 2 anchors (the first 2 levels, not the last one).

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
menu.find( "nav ul a" ).filter(function(){
  return $(this).closest('ul').find('ul').length > 0;
}).each(function() {
            console.log($(this).text() );
});
```

Demo `-->` http://jsfiddle.net/a5BeV/

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way as you want to select only direct descendants:

http://jsfiddle.net/PQVPu/

```
var menu = $('#foo');
        menu.find( "nav ul:not(:last) > li > a" ).each(function() {
           $(this).css('color','red');
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
menu.find("ul:not(:last) > li > a")
```

might be the selector you're looking for.